# Generic CloneInstance

Tags: c#, generics

I want create interface with CloneInstance method which return Generic class of that instance. For Example:

```
public interface ICloneableExtended<T> where T : this
{
    T CloneInstance();
}

public class Car : ICloneableExtended
{
   ...
   ...

   public Car CloneInstance()
   { .. }
}

Foo()
{
   Car car ...;
   var clonedCar = car.CloneInstance();
}
```

In definition of class `Car`, I need use only `ICloneableExtended`, not `ICloneableExtended<T>`. Is there some way how to do this?

Comment: That `public class Car : ICloneableExtended` should not compile. Use `public class Car : ICloneableExtended<Car>` instead and remove `where T : this`. You can't add a condition to this.

Comment: You'll need to use reflection to copy over each of the properties that you want. If you don't want to copy all `public` properties, you'll need to take a look into Attributes.

Comment: this is it. I cant use ICloneableExtended<Car>. I have to define somehow that CloneInstance() return same type as object on which was method called

Comment: For my is OK to copy all attributes manually. Problem is that normal Clone() returns object, not same type as caller

Comment: You can't enforce that there is a method that returns exactly this type. What you can do is to implement `ICloneableExtended<Car>` explicitly and if you derive that class implement it (e.g. `ICloneableExtended<SubCar>`) explicitly again. Let's say there is a way. Now you derive from `Car`. What should `CloneInstance` return? You have to change base class in that case.

Comment: You can inherit from "ICloneableExtended", but you have to cast everytime when you call the CloneInstance, you just have to change the interface to just "ICloneableExtended", just for curiosity, why cannot you use <T>?

Answer (score 0):

You can accept a generic `T` parameter for the concrete class that will implement `ICloneableExtended`:

```
interface ICloneableExtended<T> {
    Clone();
}

class Car : ICloneableExtended<Car> {
    public Car Clone() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You may consider to make `T` parameter **covariant** (if you wish to keep `ICloneableExtended<Car>` with many concrete classes - which will implement `ICloneableExtended<T>`):

```
interface ICloneableExtended<out T> {
    Clone();
}
```

Note that you may not need a *generic-less* interface, you already have `ICloneable` (with all its drawbacks and misuses):

```
interface ICloneableExtended<out T> : ICloneable {
    Clone();
}
```

For binary serializable types you may even implement a basic and reusable (but pretty inefficient) base class:

```
interface ICloneableExtended<T> : ICloneable {
    T Clone();
}

abstract class Cloneable<T> : ICloneableExtended<T> {
    public virtual T Clone() {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, this);

            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }

    object ICloneable.Clone() {
        return Clone();
    }
}

sealed class Car : Cloneable<Car> { }
```

With this approach each concrete class must implement `ICloneableExtended<T>` but you can't overload `Clone()` method differentiating only with return value then you'd better to implement `ICloneableExtended<T>` explicitly. A less confusing way (both for who implements this interface and who will use it) is to provide an **extension method**:

```
static class Extensions {
    public static T Clone<T>(this object obj) {
        var cloneable = obj as ICloneable;
        if (cloneable != null)
            return (T)cloneable.Clone();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            return (T)...
        }
    }
}
```

(here I'm using `ICloneable` for clarity but if you don't want to use it because of its worldwide *random* usage then just pick your own equivalent non-generic interface).